# Syntax when there is a space in the key

Tags: jq

This is driving me nuts.

I have a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
"gateways": [
    {
        "DHCP": "On",
        "External IPs": "46.244.46.66",
        "Firewall": "On",
        "NAT": "Off",
        "Name": "gateway",
        "Routed Networks": "photon, default-routed-network",
        "Selected": "*",
        "Syslog": "",
        "Uplinks": "d5p6v51-ext",
        "VPN": "Off"
    }
]
}
```

I can easily extract values for most of the keys.

E.g.

```
jq --raw-output .gateways[0].Name
gateway
```

However, what I really need to get is the `"External IPs"` value and I can't figure out how to manage the space.

I tried

```
jq --raw-output .gateways[0].'External IPs'

jq --raw-output .gateways[0].`External IPs`

jq --raw-output .gateways[0]."External IPs"
```

But none of these work.

Any hint?

Answer (score 32):

Use quoting as in:

```
jq --raw-output '.gateways[0]."External IPs"'
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning that in the shell, you should always quote the filter, something the OP did not do.

Comment: On older versions of jq where this syntax is not allowed, you can use `.gateways[0]["External IPs"]`

Comment: Thanks @JeffMercado and @santiago-lapesta but none of those two syntaxes work for me. I get a `compile error` at either the `[` or at the `"` depending on which of the two I try.

Comment: BTW, not sure if it makes a difference, but I am concatenating this command to populate the gateways array (e.g. `vca -j gateway | jq --raw-output '.gateways[0]."External IPs"'`)

Answer (score 2):

Ok I figured it out.

In the end what @JeffMercado suggested worked. Problem is that `apt-get install jq` install version 1.3 of jq. I had to update manually jq (to 1.5) and then it worked.

Thanks!