# jq syntax error extracting key with colon in its name

Tags: json, bash, unix, jq

I have the following JSON (which can be retrieved from https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:039397281X&format=json) as input:

```
{
  "ISBN:039397281X": {
    "bib_key": "ISBN:039397281X",
    "preview": "borrow",
    "thumbnail_url": "https://covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/7890978-S.jpg",
    "preview_url": "https://archive.org/details/isbn_9780393972818",
    "info_url": "https://openlibrary.org/books/OL348852M/Don_Quijote"
  }
}
```

My goal is to extract the `preview_url` -- thus, for the input above, to get the output `https://archive.org/details/isbn_9780393972818`.

I'm currently using the following:

```
curl 'https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:039397281X&format=json' \
  | jq -r '.ISBN:039397281X' | jq -r '.preview_url'
```

However, this emits an error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.ISBN:039397281X     
jq: 1 compile error
```

How can it be resolved?

Comment: The edits I've made to the question are intended to be an example of how similar questions should be asked in the future: There's an English-language description of what you're trying to do; code that can be copied-and-pasted to reproduce the problem; the input data (or a subset sufficient to allow folks to test the problem) is present in the question itself (so the question and its answers still make sense even if the link breaks or the content behind it changes)

Comment: Related: [jq - Syntax when there is space in the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700103/syntax-when-there-is-a-space-in-the-key); or [JQ parsing strings with `-`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880288/jq-parsing-strings-with)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you want is:

```
jq -r '.["ISBN:039397281X"].preview_url'
```

or, more simply:

```
jq -r '.[].preview_url'
```

The syntax `.foo` can only be used to extract the value associated with key `foo` when `foo` is a valid identifier. Colons are not valid in identifier names, so a different syntax (`.["foo"]`) must be used.